# Дубль данных в SQL запросе

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос следующего вида:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        items.name as Имя, 
        categories.name as Категория, 
        carts.count AS Количество, 
        carts.id as ID
FROM carts 
INNER JOIN categories 
INNER JOIN items
```

Где я хочу сделать выборку, по имени категории, имени товара, id, кол-ва товаров в корзине

Но запрос выдает [image: повторение рез-та в разных категориях]
[image: схема БД]
p.s. как задать условия связывания?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: *Но запрос выдает* Что ты попросил, то и выдаёт. А то, что ты просишь не то, что нужно - так при чём тут сервер? У тебя в запросе тупо условий связывания нет.

Comment: Akina, а как задать эти условия связывания?

Comment: @sunpressed Приведите пример ожидаемой выборки. Вручную добавьте, какие данные вы ожидаете увидеть в таблице вместо тех, что на скриншоте. Желательно подготовить маленький пример. Что хранится в таблицах, что ожидается получить после выполнения запроса.

Comment: @sunpressed *"как задать эти условия связывания?"* --- видимо через `ON`

Comment: @sunpressed По-моему вы пока сами не очень представляете как должна выглядеть выборка. Т.к. если вы хотите увидеть все перечисленные данные, то полученный результат и есть то что вы просите.

Comment: Alpensin
 Да, но я хочу, чтобы каждая запись была в единственном числе

Comment: @Alpensin связанная с выбранной категорией

Comment: Скорее всего вам ещё и не `DISTINCT` нужен, а `SUM` и `GROUP BY`. Что-то тут не вяжется.

Comment: @CrazyElf видимо, но все равно не получается разобраться

Comment: @sunpressed У вас уже каждая запись в единственном числе. Нет ни одного дубля. Скорее всего вам нужна какая-то группировка. Но тогда надо определиться по каким полям.

Answer (score 1):

Ну что-то такое должно быть. Смотрите, какой подходящий по названию `id` есть в другой таблице и вяжете к нему:

```
...
FROM carts 
INNER JOIN items ON items.id = carts.item_id
INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = items.category_id
```